# High CPU on process "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation"

Tags: 2013

Our SharePoint site suddenly got very slow (response times 5sec+). When I logged in to our WFE-server I saw that the process "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation" ran with around 90% of the CPU.

After a restart it ran fine again, and the process is now running with 0% CPU.

Any idea on why that happens and what it does. I thought most SharePoint work was done throug w3wp and timer jobs.

Running Win Server 2012, SharePoint 2013

Ok, this is NOT a hardware problem. We have one WFE and one app server. It have been running smoothly until this. It keeps happening and as of now, the only solution I have is restart the server

Comment: You can try to run Performance monitor and find out what process taking a lot of CPU. It could be timer jobs

Comment: What? I know the process' name, its "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation".

Comment: Opps my bad, can you update your post with your hardware configuration. Like RAM, HD and how many WFEs and others

Comment: Sharepoint Search can cause performance issues sometimes. Try to change Search configuration to crawl at night, by example. But default it crawls every 5 minutes imho

Comment: ok, thanks for the tip...does search run on WFE? Anyway, Ill try that and get back about the result (might take some days to verify)